# How to pass ID as argument in JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, html

HTML body:

```
<div id = "id1">
    <input type="text" class="name">
    <input type="button" onclick="myFunction(id1)" value="Click me">
</div>

<div id = "id2">
    <input type="text" class="name">
    <input type="button" onclick="myFunction(id2)" value="Click me">
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function myFunction(param)
{
    var content = document.getElementById("param");
    var x = content.getElementByClassName("name").value;
    alert(x);
}
```

I want to use passed ID in the JavaScript function to get more values.

Comment: You cannot use the same `name` id for many input text. This is not valid.

Comment: You can't have more than one component with the same `id`. You have to change the `id` of the second div

Comment: `id` should be unique in html

Comment: Id should be unique you need to use class attribute for input tag

Comment: If you just need the value of the text boxes, you can have unique ID for the text box.. and on click of the function, you can pass the ID from HTML to the JS function. And read the value of the text box. That will be one approach..

Comment: Even after changing the(id to class), it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the id parameters in to the onclick events as strings. Then give each text input a class of `name`, not an `id` (ids have to be unique to a single element). Finally, use the id param to find the container element using `getElementById`, and use `querySelector` to drill down to the text input.

```js
function myFunction(param)
{
  let el = document.getElementById(param)
  let name = el.querySelector('input.name').value
  console.log(name)
}
```

```html
<div id = "id1">
    <input type="text" class="name">
    <input type="button" onclick="myFunction('id1')" value="Click me">
</div>

<div id = "id2">
    <input type="text" class="name">
    <input type="button" onclick="myFunction('id2')" value="Click me">
</div>
```

Comment: Is it necessary to use 'input.name' or we can simply use 'name'

Comment: @PawanAsipu you can use ‘.name’ if you want. The leading period tells the function that ‘name’ is a class.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below. i have kept id of text box different. And the ID is passed to the function from HTML. This is one of the approaches to get the value from the text-box.

Update: Used class on name text box. And fetch values for the element with class value of 'name'.

```
<div id = "id1">
  <input type="text" class="name">
  <input type="button" onclick="myFunction('id1')" value="Click me">
</div>

<div id = "id2">
  <input type="text" class="name">
  <input type="button" onclick="myFunction('id2')" value="Click me">
</div>

function myFunction(param) {
  const divElement = document.getElementById(param);
  const txt = divElement.getElementsByClassName('name')[0].value
  console.log(txt);
}
```

JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sagarag05/Lm7fn6dx/10/

Let me know if this works.

Comment: let say my div tag contains 10 ids and I have 10 div tags. Then I can't change all id names right. Instead of id, I have changed it to class. Can you help me with this now

Comment: Sure, let me update my code.. give me 2 mins.

Comment: @PawanAsipu - Updated my JS Fiddle and code above. Give it a try and it will work ..

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction(param)
{
    var content = document.getElementById(param.id);
    var x = content.getElementsByClassName("name")[0].value;
    alert(x);
}
```

```html
<div id = "id1">
    <input type="text" class="name" id="name">
    <input type="button" onclick="myFunction(id1)" value="Click me">
</div>

<div id = "id2">
    <input type="text" class="name" id="name1">
    <input type="button" onclick="myFunction(id2)" value="Click me">
</div>
```

here is the above working snippet of your question.
check the above changes here I used `param.id` instead of only `param`
also, your using the class selector so class selector gives response in array format so I had used `getElementsByClassName("name")[0].value`.

Comment: It works. But, can you please explain, why param.id?

Comment: because  param gives a bunch of objects includes of tag name class name and many more, so I used `param.id`

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction(btn){
  const [input] = btn.parentElement.children;
  console.log('input value: ' + input.value);
}
```

```html
<div id = "id1">
    <input type="text" class="name">
    <input type="button" onclick="myFunction(this)" value="Click me">
</div>

<div id = "id2">
    <input type="text" class="name">
    <input type="button" onclick="myFunction(this)" value="Click me">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `querySelector` to get the `input` value having type `text`

```js
function myFunction(param)
{
    var content = document.getElementById(param);
    alert(content.querySelector('input[type="text"]').value);
}
```

```html
<div id = "id1">
    <input type="text" class="name">
    <input type="button" onclick="myFunction('id1')" value="Click me">
</div>

<div id = "id2">
    <input type="text" class="name">
    <input type="button" onclick="myFunction('id2')" value="Click me">
</div>
```